# TableView only shows content when clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I'm making a TableView to show the shops in our town, along with their category. I have a problem with showing the shops in the table view: first off, the first shop doesn't show, and second, the shops only become visible when clicked upon. You can find a video of the problem [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B66972SsSRztZlRZUnJjcXpubmM)

The code of the table view:

```
import UIKit

class MasterTableViewController: UITableViewController {

// MARK: - Properties
var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
var winkels = [Winkel]()

// MARK: - View Setup
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    winkels = [
        Winkel(category:"Literature", name:"Standaard"),
        Winkel(category:"Literature", name:"Acco"),
        Winkel(category:"Clothing", name:"H&M"),
        Winkel(category:"Clothing", name:"C&A"),
        Winkel(category:"Clothing", name:"Patio"),
        Winkel(category:"Restaurants", name:"De 46"),
        Winkel(category:"Restaurants", name:"Het hoekske"),
        Winkel(category:"Supermarkets", name:"Carrefour"),
        Winkel(category:"Supermarkets", name:"Colruyt")
    ]

    if let splitViewController = splitViewController {
        let controllers = splitViewController.viewControllers
        detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count - 1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = splitViewController!.collapsed
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

// MARK: - Table View
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return winkels.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)


    let winkel = winkels[indexPath.row]
    cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    cell.textLabel!.text = winkel.name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = winkel.category
    return cell
}

// MARK: - Segues
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let winkel = winkels[indexPath.row]
            let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
            controller.detailWinkel = winkel
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        }
    }
 }

}
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix these problems? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the line
`cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")`   cause you already have
`var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)`

Comment: If i do that, indeed it shows all the names instantly, but the category isn't shown, and it doesn't when i click it either. Can i combine the both?

Comment: Yes, just change your cell prototype Style to Subtitle from storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line at the end of your `viewDidLoad` function

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Hmm it doesn't appear to do anything :/